# How can I submit ionic radio button form to sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

I have created an ionic app which contains a radio button form. I have a problem connecting the radio button form to the sqlite database. The database should be able to store radio values selected by a user after submission.

this is my code

```
<form [formGroup]="ngForm" (submit)="submit()">
   <ion-list>
     <ion-radio-group formControlName="radioSelection">
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 1</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="1"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Option 2</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="2"></ion-radio>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
<ion-button color="dark" type="submit" expand="block">Submit</ion-button>
</form>
```

this is my .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-four',
  templateUrl: './four.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./four.page.scss'],
})
export class FourPage implements OnInit {

 constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder
               ) {}

ngOnInit() {
  }

submitForm() {
     this.radioValue = this.ngForm.get('radioSelection').value;
}
}
```

Comment: this.ngForm.controls.radioSelection.value

Comment: please provide the error you get